# How to change the keys of multidimensional array in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, associative-array

My multidimensional array named `$cs_map_data` is as follows :

```
Array
(
    [2] => Array
        (
            [class_id] => 2
            [class_name] => II
            [class_checked] => 0
            [class_subjects] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [cs_map_id] => 81
                            [subject_name] => 11 Engllish
                            [subject_checked] => 0
                            [teacher_cs_id] => 
                        )

                )

        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [class_id] => 3
            [class_name] => III
            [class_checked] => 0
            [class_subjects] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [cs_map_id] => 155
                            [subject_name] => Hidi
                            [subject_checked] => 0
                            [teacher_cs_id] => 
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [cs_map_id] => 156
                            [subject_name] => 11 Maths
                            [subject_checked] => 0
                            [teacher_cs_id] => 
                        )

                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [cs_map_id] => 157
                            [subject_name] => 11 Science
                            [subject_checked] => 0
                            [teacher_cs_id] => 
                        )

                    [3] => Array
                        (
                            [cs_map_id] => 158
                            [subject_name] => 11 Engllish
                            [subject_checked] => 0
                            [teacher_cs_id] => 
                        )

                )

        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [class_id] => 4
            [class_name] => IV
            [class_checked] => 0
            [class_subjects] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [cs_map_id] => 86
                            [subject_name] => Physics
                            [subject_checked] => 0
                            [teacher_cs_id] => 
                        )

                )

        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [class_id] => 6
            [class_name] => VI
            [class_checked] => 0
            [class_subjects] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [cs_map_id] => 144
                            [subject_name] => Mathematics
                            [subject_checked] => 0
                            [teacher_cs_id] => 
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [cs_map_id] => 145
                            [subject_name] => Biology
                            [subject_checked] => 0
                            [teacher_cs_id] => 
                        )

                )

        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [class_id] => 7
            [class_name] => VII
            [class_checked] => 0
            [class_subjects] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [cs_map_id] => 129
                            [subject_name] => Physics
                            [subject_checked] => 0
                            [teacher_cs_id] => 
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [cs_map_id] => 130
                            [subject_name] => Chemistry11
                            [subject_checked] => 0
                            [teacher_cs_id] => 
                        )

                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [cs_map_id] => 131
                            [subject_name] => 11 Science
                            [subject_checked] => 0
                            [teacher_cs_id] => 
                        )

                )

        )

    [8] => Array
        (
            [class_id] => 8
            [class_name] => VIII
            [class_checked] => 0
            [class_subjects] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [cs_map_id] => 67
                            [subject_name] => Hidi
                            [subject_checked] => 0
                            [teacher_cs_id] => 
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [cs_map_id] => 68
                            [subject_name] => 11 Engllish
                            [subject_checked] => 0
                            [teacher_cs_id] => 
                        )

                )

        )

    [9] => Array
        (
            [class_id] => 9
            [class_name] => IX
            [class_checked] => 0
            [class_subjects] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [cs_map_id] => 87
                            [subject_name] => Mathematics
                            [subject_checked] => 0
                            [teacher_cs_id] => 
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [cs_map_id] => 88
                            [subject_name] => Hidi
                            [subject_checked] => 0
                            [teacher_cs_id] => 
                        )

                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [cs_map_id] => 89
                            [subject_name] => 11 Science
                            [subject_checked] => 0
                            [teacher_cs_id] => 
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

If you notice, the keys of array are `[2],[3],[4],[6],[7],[8],[9]`. These keys I've obtained from some function defined by some other developer. Now my requirement is to rename these keys i.e. the array keys should be `[0],[1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6]`. Other array elements and other key-value pairs should be as it is. I googled about it but couldn't get the solution. Can anyone help me to reorder these array keys? Thanks in advance. My required output is as follows :

```
Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [class_id] => 2
                [class_name] => II
                [class_checked] => 0
                [class_subjects] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [cs_map_id] => 81
                                [subject_name] => 11 Engllish
                                [subject_checked] => 0
                                [teacher_cs_id] => 
                            )

                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [class_id] => 3
            [class_name] => III
            [class_checked] => 0
            [class_subjects] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [cs_map_id] => 155
                            [subject_name] => Hidi
                            [subject_checked] => 0
                            [teacher_cs_id] => 
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [cs_map_id] => 156
                            [subject_name] => 11 Maths
                            [subject_checked] => 0
                            [teacher_cs_id] => 
                        )

                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [cs_map_id] => 157
                            [subject_name] => 11 Science
                            [subject_checked] => 0
                            [teacher_cs_id] => 
                        )

                    [3] => Array
                        (
                            [cs_map_id] => 158
                            [subject_name] => 11 Engllish
                            [subject_checked] => 0
                            [teacher_cs_id] => 
                        )

                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [class_id] => 4
            [class_name] => IV
            [class_checked] => 0
            [class_subjects] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [cs_map_id] => 86
                            [subject_name] => Physics
                            [subject_checked] => 0
                            [teacher_cs_id] => 
                        )

                )

        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [class_id] => 6
            [class_name] => VI
            [class_checked] => 0
            [class_subjects] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [cs_map_id] => 144
                            [subject_name] => Mathematics
                            [subject_checked] => 0
                            [teacher_cs_id] => 
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [cs_map_id] => 145
                            [subject_name] => Biology
                            [subject_checked] => 0
                            [teacher_cs_id] => 
                        )

                )

        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [class_id] => 7
            [class_name] => VII
            [class_checked] => 0
            [class_subjects] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [cs_map_id] => 129
                            [subject_name] => Physics
                            [subject_checked] => 0
                            [teacher_cs_id] => 
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [cs_map_id] => 130
                            [subject_name] => Chemistry11
                            [subject_checked] => 0
                            [teacher_cs_id] => 
                        )

                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [cs_map_id] => 131
                            [subject_name] => 11 Science
                            [subject_checked] => 0
                            [teacher_cs_id] => 
                        )

                )

        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [class_id] => 8
            [class_name] => VIII
            [class_checked] => 0
            [class_subjects] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [cs_map_id] => 67
                            [subject_name] => Hidi
                            [subject_checked] => 0
                            [teacher_cs_id] => 
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [cs_map_id] => 68
                            [subject_name] => 11 Engllish
                            [subject_checked] => 0
                            [teacher_cs_id] => 
                        )

                )

        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [class_id] => 9
            [class_name] => IX
            [class_checked] => 0
            [class_subjects] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [cs_map_id] => 87
                            [subject_name] => Mathematics
                            [subject_checked] => 0
                            [teacher_cs_id] => 
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [cs_map_id] => 88
                            [subject_name] => Hidi
                            [subject_checked] => 0
                            [teacher_cs_id] => 
                        )

                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [cs_map_id] => 89
                            [subject_name] => 11 Science
                            [subject_checked] => 0
                            [teacher_cs_id] => 
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

Comment: have you seen [`array_values`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php)?

Comment: I am not sure how array_values will work with multidimensional array.. but you can always loop through the array and copy the array to a new array $newArr[] = $oldArraynthElement

Answer (score 0):

It's just a matter of [array_values](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php) as Dave suggested.

In your case it looks like you need to re-index the outermost array and the 'class_subjects' elements one level down.

For the outer level, that's easy.  Say the whole thing is stored in variable `$a`, then

```
$a = array_values($a);
```

and the outermost array is re-indexed!

The inner arrays are a tad more challenging, I'd suggest giving [foreach](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) a try and using a *reference* for the value component.

Again, assume the outermost array is stored in `$a` and that's already been re-indexed, now

```
$a = array_values($a);
foreach($a as $i => &$sub)
  $sub['class_subjects'] = array_values($sub['class_subjects']);
```

and you're all done.

Answer (score 0):

As here you want to re-index the outer array indexes, [array_values($arr)](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php) will work perfectly with it.
You can try with example .

```
<?php
$arr = array(
    'foo' => 'foo',
    'bar' => array(
        'baz' => 'baz',
        'candy' => 'candy',
        'vegetable' => array(
            'carrot' => 'carrot',
        )
    ),
    'vegetable' => array(
        'carrot' => 'carrot2',
    ),
    'fruits' => 'fruits',
);
// Pass your array as argument
$arr1 = array_values($arr);
print_r($arr1);
?>
```

And if you want to iterate recursively to inner arrays, you can refer examples given in [array_values](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php) . Hope it solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
print_r(array_values($array));
```